# Is there a built-in Windows command-line editor?

Tags: windows, powershell, text-editor

When I connect to a 64-Bit Windows server via PowerShell e.g., is there some *built-in command-line tool* that allows *text editing* (assuming that I cannot/do not want to install software)?

For Linux, e.g., I can expect that there is `vi` installed on virtually every system. For old DOS/Windows version, there has been `edit.exe` which seems not to be there anymore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497399/basic-text-editor-in-command-prompt

Comment: FYI `edit` (16 bit) only ships w/ 32bit versions of Windows

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, I just added the requirement to my question.

Comment: @StefanSprenger Based on that question (and their answers), it seems that there is no such thing as a built-in edit, right?

Comment: @jaw I think there is nothing on 64 bit :-/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit a text file on the console in 64-bit Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045077/edit-a-text-file-on-the-console-in-64-bit-windows)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Why has this question been put on hold? I was not asking for they best tool, I specifically asked whether there is a built-in tool at all that I don't know of. Should i further describe the "problem"? I just want to edit a text file on the shell.

Comment: It was put on hold because 5 people voted it to be closed. Yu Hao and user2062950 both voted that they thought you where asking for was off topic (recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource), I voted that it was a duplicate of the question I posted in my comment, we can't tell what Hong Ooi and Lightness Races in Orbit voted for.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Unfortunately, the "duplicate" question did not ask for a built-in tool or at least all answers are based on 3rd-party tools.

Comment: @yu-hao: Same question to you: Why has this question been put on hold? I was not asking for they best tool, I specifically asked whether there is a built-in tool. There are are only two answers possible: 1.) There is not editor or 2.) There is an editor called "xyz.exe". So could you please reopen the question?

Comment: `cat`, `type`, `more` will display file contents.
Can also be stored in variables eg. in `for` loop for editing.
Then redirect edited variables back to file.
`type` & `echo` can also output text to file.<br>
`findstr`, `find`, substring & substitution of strings can speed up the process.
This question is closed, there's nowhere to post an answer, else I'd post an example.

Tested on Powershell & CMD on Win 10 x64

Answer (score 1):

(not enough reputation to comment, so will do it here)

As far as I know, there's not a built-in editor; however, a workaround would be to use:

```
type CON>myfile.txt
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824178/how-do-you-redirect-standard-input-to-a-file-in-the-windows-command-line), this will forward the input in the console to your file. Not nice, not powerfull, but it may help sometimes.

Please note this WON'T work through Powershell, but you may use it with `winrs -r:server cmd` or with `psexec`.