# Anaconda (Windows) alternative to nano?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, nano

So I've been following this tutorial to download Keras with a Tensorflow backend:

https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation

It has gone fairly smoothly, and I'm only stuck for a stupid reason on the final step. It asks me to run mnist_mlp.py to test if it is working, but I don't have that file downloaded. I figured I could just type 'nano mnist_mlp.py' and then copy over the code for the file and then run it, as I would do in Linux. However, since I am on windows, it is telling me in the Anaconda prompt that nano is not a recognized command.

So, how can I create a python file in Anaconda? I've tried looking it up several times, but nothing helpful has come up. Perhaps I am asking the wrong question, for I am quite new to python. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you are almost surely asking the wrong question. But well... just [download](https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) that file (e.g. right-click save as on the *raw* button)! But i have to admit. I would not touch complex software without being comfortable editing and running files on my OS.

Comment: I know I could do that, but for future reference, there must be some way I could create and edit a python file directly from the Anaconda prompt, no?

Comment: No, you don't edit files within Python itself. You do it via your OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic text editor in command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497399/basic-text-editor-in-command-prompt)

Comment: Make sure you understand what the anaconda prompt is (and then add any compatible console-editor you want). Don't get the idea it's the only way of using / working with anaconda. I'm an anaconda-user for years and never started this prompt.

Comment: @sascha Ok, I'll look more into anacoda and just create the files in my OS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use nano from the Anaconda prompt on Windows as long as the Anaconda prompt can locate the executable file in your file system.

Installing Git on Windows will often give you a version of nano that the Anaconda prompt can locate.  If you don't want Git, you can also install nano from the conda-forge channel using conda:

```
conda install --channel conda-forge nano
```

Installing nano with conda should ensure that the Anaconda prompt can locate it.