# Again with Powershell: I know how to create a file but I don't know how to write in it

Tags: powershell, shell

The thing is, It's true that using `-append sth` you can add simple things to a certain file but, actually, what I meant to write in the file it's a program made in Powershell.
In briefs, I have to execute a certain file.ps1 which contains a bunch of PowerShell coded lines but I don't know how to write these code lines inside of it.
Thanks again.

Comment: take a look at >>> `Get-Help *content*` <<< [*grin*]

Comment: There are a few ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045077/edit-a-text-file-on-the-console-using-powershell) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/938093/nano-alternative-for-windows-powershell).